# How to wait for an okay button before starting a new activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, messagebox

Good day.I have a problem, I am displaying a message box when a button is clicked.The message box simple shows a confirmation of registration.After that I open a new activity.
The problem is that it shows the messagebox and then starts the new activity without waiting for the ok  button to be clicked.How can I only display the new activity upon clicking the ok button.

Below is the code I used.

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.registerButton);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BookingActivity.class);
                AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                dlgAlert.setMessage("You have successfully Registered.Please Press okay to continue");
                dlgAlert.setTitle("Registration");
                dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                dlgAlert.setCancelable(false);
                dlgAlert.create().show();


                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Changed the code to

```
 @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               // Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BookingActivity.class);
                AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                dlgAlert.setMessage("You have successfully Registered.Please Press okay to continue");
                dlgAlert.setTitle("Registration");
                dlgAlert.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BookingActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                dlgAlert.setCancelable(false);
                dlgAlert.show();
```

Comment: Add `listener` for `OK` click and inside that do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Don't start activity there. Remove the line `startActivity(intent)` and `finish()`. You need to do this

```
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.label_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(your arguments here) 
        startActivity(intent);
     }
});
builder.show();
```

So all you need to do is change the line to `setPositiveButton` and use as given above.

As per your style, you are not setting action to the dialog but to the button that displays the dialog.

Comment: okay, I am new to android so I am struggling.Was thinking, Cant I have some if statement to see if the ok button was clicked and put the startactivity in that if statement.Because I do not understand your code

Comment: The code inside DialogInterface.OnClickListener only will trigger when the user click the button.

Comment: You don't need to check for which button was clicked. setPositiveButton will check for OK and setNegativeButton will check for CANCEL

Comment: So, what is builder?It also says cannot resolve DialogInterface.I am confused now.*I solved that.Let me try to run it and see

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.registerButton);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                dlgAlert.setMessage("You have successfully Registered.Please Press okay to continue");
                dlgAlert.setTitle("Registration");
                dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                dlgAlert.setCancelable(false);
                dlgAlert.create().show();
                dlgAlert.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BookingActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent); 
               }
         });
     }
});
```

Comment: Sorry but I doubt this to be correct. You have dlgAlert inside the onClick and hence can't use it outside.

Comment: i have edited my ans. is it fine now? please point out if i am doind something wrong

Comment: Thanks! Special for pointing out the error. That's how we learn :)